# Parsing a textfile (with HTML in it) with C++

Tags: c++, parsing, html

I've been able to get some raw data in the form of a html webpage, which I have in turn put into an ordinary text file.  I'm currently trying to use a C++ program to parse this file, but for some reason it's giving me weird output in that it's putting @s, symbols, and ^Ms in between every single letter.  I'm unsure as to whether this is because I'm trying to parse an HTML file or if it's because my code is wrong, but I've tried my code on smaller HTML files and it works fine.  The file I want it to work on is just 145kB

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(argv[1]);
  string str;

  while(getline(inFile, str))
  {
    cout << str << endl;
  }

}
```

If anyone could give me a clue as to why this isn't working, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I suspect your code prints exactly what's in the file. Examine the file in the hex viewer to confirm.

Comment: Hi I think it may be the character encoding used by html file is different from yours. Your program uses ANSI string, while most html files are using unicode (not sure), which means, each character uses more than one byte to encode itself. That is why you see weird character when you read it byte by byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML files may come in virtually any encoding. OP needs to open the file, according the encoding that it has, that is typically supplied by the web browser he got it from as part of the page serve.  Note that *each* individual page served up by the same site, may have *different* encodings. The "@" are probably actually printed as "^@", which is what many output routines will print if you give them null characters.   He may have a UTF-16 file, and is reading it assuming it is ASCII 8 bit.

He also needs to understand that "newline" conventions vary between machines; his "^M" probably means he is running on a Unix machine (which thinks "^J" is a line break, and he got his file from a Windows box, which thinks "^M^J" is a line break. Welcome to the real world.

Next, OP will find that parsing HTML is actually hard because it is complex, has lots of crazy character conventions (above and beyond encoding), and often is often simply illegal because the browsers allow it, and not every checks that their HTML is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  wifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(argv[1]);
  wstring str;

  while(getline(inFile, str))
  {
      wcout << str << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. When I try this it prints nothing.